# Submenu item linked to anchor in parent's content

Tags: routes, navigation

I would like to have a multi-level menu where some of the menus are links not to a content node, but just for inline anchors specified in the parent node's content source.

Is there an already existing solution for this feature? If not, what method should I choose for not to spend too much time on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

[Special menu items](http://drupal.org/project/special_menu_items)

[Menu Firstchild](http://drupal.org/project/menu_firstchild)

Comment: I've read these module's descriptions and I am not sure if they have some unmentioned features or I could use them in a way which is not explained on their homepages, because if not, then neither of these it's what I am looking for.  I would like to add menu items with anchor paths where the path is generated from a text, just like any other normal path alias would be, so then I could copy these URLs into a content  html as anchors.